# Why can't I assign a value to the name `_i` in iPython?

Tags: python, ipython

If I do:

```
_j = 1

print(_j)
1
```

This is as expected

But if I:

```
_i = 1

print(_i)
_i = 1
```

Not at all what I expected.  Why is `_i` special and what other names have this property that I cannot overwrite it?

Comment: `>>> _i = 1; 
>>> print(_i); 
1` - Not at all sure what you're talking about :/ Is it a lower-case `I`? (tried in Python3.6.2)

Comment: _i also prints the expression, _j prints just the value

Comment: are you using PssPy? A quick google search shows that _i is a special variable in that case.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.  And this is iPython via anaconda

Comment: @Torxed seems as if it prints out normally if you include it in the same line of code.  However, when split into two lines, IPython has had a chance to overwrite it again.

Comment: Cool, never used anaconda, iPython or really anything besides `python.exe`/`/usr/bin/python` heh. So I've never experienced these artifacts. Still, interesting that it replaces `_i` on every line of execution. Must be some overhead there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using IPython, and `_i` has a special meaning pertaining specifically to IPython. In Python more generally, you can do such an assignment.

In IPython:

```
In [1]: _i = 1
In [2]: _i
Out[2]: '_i = 1'
```

In the standard Python REPL:

```
>>> _i = 1
>>> _i
1
```

More information here: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#input-caching-system

Comment: That link is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using ipython? In ipython _i means your previous command.